# What is the purpose of parent::beforeSave in Yii Framework?

Tags: yii

```
protected  function  beforeSave()
{
    if ( parent :: beforeSave())
    {
        if ( $this -> isNewRecord )
             $this -> create_time =time () ;
        return true ;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is code from the demo blog within Yii framework,I do not know the purpose of parent :: beforeSave(),why we should use it ?I am new to PHP thanks !

Answer (score 3):

`beforeSave()` is an internal **CActiveRecord** function that normally [fires](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L893) `onBeforeSave` [event](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/). You should call `parent::beforeSave()` in your overriden function in a subclassed record if you want to fire this event. Or do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeSave()` is very useful. You can assign variable with different values on add or update record by checking `isNewRecord`. And this is a commonn place to assing some variables like create_time, generating uuid. You can do this at anywhere but it's better if they are at common place.

Also you should consider it as a better way programming that has been proved by Yii.

Comment: Overriden `beforeSave()` is useful, not `parent::beforeSave()`. Second one is just a call to parent's function implementation which is “constant”.